# PHP Google sheets quickstart

Tags: php, google-sheets

I would like to export data to google sheets, I downloaded quickstart.php script from https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php I launched script from cli, it asks a "Enter verification code:" and give me a url to open with browser, I allow permission and redirect to a script I have to my server which display array it receives:

```
[access_token] => ....

[expires_in] => 3599
[refresh_token] => ...
[scope] => ....
[token_type] => Bearer
[created] => 1589307422
```

I paste access_token to cli asking code but it returns:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Invalid token format in /var/www/html/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php:449
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/quickstart.php(45): Google_Client->setAccessToken(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/quickstart.php(63): getClient()
#2 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html//vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php on line 449
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: How are you pasting the access_token array to the client?

Comment: I Made a script which print_r the array I receive from Google.I copy the access_token array element and I Paste into the cli I launched quickstart.php

Comment: You passed it as a `STDIN`? I think it has to be cast as an Array to be parsed correctly.

Comment: I don't know how to pass it as an array because quickstart.php need to be launched from cli, it return me a url (to open from a browser which ask for autorization to use google sheets) and ask for Enter verification code: and I think is asking for access token

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar I kind of did this:

Replace (temporarily)

```
$authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));
```

With:

```
$authCode = '4/yQFYBDGKFDSD54546Qhg6BZlT_gCEFZ7ixATB7657oc';
```

Because I had that auth code somewhere...

Hope you can do that too to get it started, Surely not the best way to do it, but that's what I did.

Comment: Hi, are you still using this solution or did you by any chance figure out anything else?

Comment: It is working on live site at the moment, haven't had to look at it anymore

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

The code it's asking is not the access token. The access token will be actually retrieved by this authorization flow.

It's actually as easy as following the tutorial:

> Once you get the quickstart up and running, it will prompt you to authorize access:
>
> Browse to the provided URL in your web browser.
>
> If you are not already logged into your Google account, you will be prompted to log in. If you are logged into multiple Google accounts, you will be asked to select one account to use for the authorization.
>
> Click the Accept button.
>
> Copy the code you're given, paste it into the command-line prompt, and press Enter.

### Reference

[PHP quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php#step_4_run_the_sample)

Comment: No it no gives any code ask to authorize and redirect to the script I have which is this:require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$code = $_GET["code"];
$client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
$token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
echo "<PRE>";
print_r($token);
echo "</PRE>";

Comment: Ok then, you already have the authorization code and the access token. You therefore completed the auth flow successfully.